# how to solve gcloud app deploy network connectivity error?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When I try to deploy my Django project on Google App Engine with command:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

then i got network connectivity error every time. Error massage is:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:661)
This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.
```

I try google but not solve it. Please anyone help me.

My `app.yaml` file is:

```
runtime: python37

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 scanner_api.wsgi

handlers:
  # This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
  # directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

  # This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
  # required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
  # the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: no.i don't use proxy.

Comment: What's the output of `gcloud --version`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try after lowering the number of parallel tasks by setting GAM_THREADS environment variable:

```
$env:GAM_THREADS=5
```

If you get the same error, keep it lowering by 4,3,2 ...

try `gcloud app deploy --log-http` you may get more information about the error

Try changing your network too if nothing help...like mobile hotspot!!

Comment: i try it.but it's not working on my environment but why i don't know.Thank for your reply.

Comment: actually when i change my wifi then solved this error.it ruins my two days.

Answer (score 0):

Your `openssl` is either missing or out of date. Run:

```
python -m pip install pyopenssl
```

and try again.

Comment: my pyopenssl is up to date.still gcloud app deploy show this error.

Comment: What is the output of `python --version`, `python2 --version` and `python3 --version`?

Comment: python --version is Python 3.7.3

Comment: Try `python2 -m pip install pyopenssl` then.

Comment: python2' is not recognized as an internal or external command..why i use python2..already i use python latest version